# Can claims be amended after patent contents become public?

Tags: claims, claim-amendment

I have filed non provisional, regular utility patents applications. I will be also filing continuation applications. Can I add or amend claims after the content is made public? Such as in a crowd funding campaign?

Answer (score 4):

You can amend and add claims in the application and can file continuation and divisional applications from it with new claims. However, any added or amended claims need to be fully supported in the original application's disclosure. "No new matter", after the filing data, is a strict rule.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I do that after publication?

Comment: @PaulPage The answer is yes. In fact you probably will in the course of getting the patent.